# During thread contention how can I speed up this ConcurrentQueue implementation which uses ReaderWriterLockSlim over a regular Queue<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, queue, micro-optimization

**Question:** How can I implement a faster thread safe queue to support an object pool when under heavy thread contention?

**Scenario:** My overall final objective is a pure Dot Net implementation of a Micro Services host with performance as a feature: https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX

**Example Use Case:** Unity ML Agents using TorchSharp but also able to utilize the processing power of multiple NVidia cards (in my case 4X 3090 cards). Performance is critical because PPO machine learning requires many millions of iterations before it even begins to learn. In other words very tight loops serializing data messages hundreds of millions of times as fast as possible. With this current code depending on the model I get between 2 to 6 million iterations per day (depending on the model) and it is only enough data to utilize one of the four video cards at around 60%.

Custom Implementation of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` using `ReaderWriterLockSlim`
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/ThreadSafeQueue.cs

Turns out it is slightly faster than using `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>`

Note: both `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and ThreadSafeQueue.cs above are extremely fast when there is NO thread contention. However when there is high thread contention (example 4 threads in tight loops) it tends to struggle.

**Objective:** I am looking for a way to create a queue with faster performance than this during thread contention. Attempts at a lock free queue (see below) did not perform any better.

I am aware that this may be considered a Micro Optimization.
The reason I need this to run faster is because this scenario is for machine learning (or other high volume transaction processing) where I have multiple producers (agents) feeding requests (messages) or training data to a central instance (consumer). For the machine learning scenario the central instance is executing these requests against Tensorflow.Net / TorchSharp running across 4 X 3090 video cards. the Tensorflow.Net / TorchSharp model is Proximal Policy optimization and therefore the result of each request then needs to be sent back to the producer (agent). I need to be able to serialize well over 200K messages per second to fully utilize the four video cards. However I am only able to get a throughput of around 43K messages per second. Each message is multiple float[] arrays plus control parameters such as score (float) step (int) etc... The overall reason why I need this performance is because I am trying to cut down 1 month for a training run down to about 1 week.

I'm using the Thread safe queue as a singleton to provide a backing store for object pooling for serialization across TCP sockets in a custom message queue implementation. The objects being pooled are management objects which wrap `ArrayPool<byte>` buffers in order to:

**A)** manage the renting and returning of `ArrayPool<T>` buffers
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/RentedBuffer.cs

**B)** Guarantee the returning of rented buffers in order to prevent memory leaks
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/RentedBufferContract.cs

Minimal GC collection overheads is also a very important factor.

Object Pooling code is here:
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/ManagedPool.cs

Consider that serializing an object with say 30 array properties / fields marked for serialization results in not one buffer but multiple. This is because the buffers are used for the array properties themselves as well as for the byte buffers used in serialization. Plus packing an object which has other object properties means nested levels of serialization which requires even more buffers.
The Serializer itself is here:

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Serialization/TypedSerializer.cs

I'm using a custom extended version of BitConverter which reads from and writes to afore mentioned (pooled) rented buffers:

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Serialization/BitConverterExtended.cs

Note: I realize I could use `MemoryPool<T>` however that does not solve my issue because using `MemoryPool<T>` would require creating yet another class to manage its renting and returning as it does NOT autoreturn when it goes out of scope.

Note: For the end solution (Message Queue) Already looked at ZeroMQ, RabitMQ etc... but I need faster speeds. In fact I was previously using ZeroMQ with MessagePack but I need faster speeds. The issue with MessagePack + ZeroMQ is not their native speed itself. Rather its to do with the amount of allocations and therefore GC Collection overheads.

Hence I've written from scratch serializer, socket transport, and object pooling. For which a thread safe queue is a basic building block. In my current implementation when under heavy thread contention the performance gains from the serializer are negated by the queue implementation where I am using it for object pooling of wrappers around ArrayPool< T > for managing their return and preventing memory leaks. These objects must be pooled because otherwise we are back to the issue of GC collection overheads.

Tried Julian M Bucknall's Lock Free Queue.
https://secondboyet.com/Articles/LockfreeQueue.html
However his implementation generates an allocation for each queue insert which creates a massive amount of garbage. End result is it ends up with 60% time spent in GC.

Tried extending it using object pooling however since the object pool uses the above ThreadSafeQueue implementation it is bottlenecked on the performance of the same.

Extended (optional object pooling) implementation of Julian M Bucknall's Lock Free Queue is here:

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/TestApps/ChillX.MQServer.Benchmark/LockFreeQueue.cs

Next implemented a lock free structure from scratch without pooling but using a queue of ring buffers to minimize allocations. Its performance is twice as fast as the LockFreeQueue above. 367ms vs 607ms for 1000000 queue / dequeue operations across 8 threads. however it is still 50% slower than ThreadSafeQueue which uses ReaderWriterLockSlim. Note LockFreeRingBufferQueue is a 99% lock free implementation:

https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/ChillX.Core/Structures/LockFreeRingBufferQueue.cs

Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Benchmark Code is here: https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/blob/master/src/TestApps/ChillX.MQServer.Benchmark/Bench_Queue.cs

If running the benchmark App (link below) choose option 2 from the menu.
https://github.com/tcwicks/ChillX/tree/master/src/TestApps/ChillX.MQServer.Benchmark

Here are the benchmark results using Benchmark.Net comparing above mentioned LockFreeQueue (Lock Free) versus ThreadSafeQueue (ReaderWriterLockSlim) versus the standard ConcurrentQueue:

Note: ConcurrentQueueCount method is checking the count before TryDequeue. ConcurrentQueueTry is doing a TryDequeue without checking the count.

```
/*
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19044.1645 (21H2)
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970X, 1 CPU, 64 logical and 32 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.202
  [Host]   : .NET 6.0.4 (6.0.422.16404), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  .NET 6.0 : .NET 6.0.4 (6.0.422.16404), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET 6.0  Runtime=.NET 6.0

|                 Method |           m_TestMode | numRepititions | numThreads |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |     Gen 0 | Completed Work Items | Lock Contentions |     Gen 1 |     Gen 2 |    Allocated |
|----------------------- |--------------------- |--------------- |----------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|---------------------:|-----------------:|----------:|----------:|-------------:|
| Bench_QueuePerformance |        LockFreeQueue |        1000000 |          4 | 607.8 ms | 11.97 ms | 15.14 ms | 5000.0000 |                    - |                - | 3000.0000 | 1000.0000 | 40,002,976 B |
| Bench_QueuePerformance |      ThreadSafeQueue |        1000000 |          4 | 322.0 ms | 19.68 ms | 58.02 ms |         - |                    - |                - |         - |         - |        992 B |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ConcurrentQueueCount |        1000000 |          4 | 421.2 ms |  8.38 ms | 14.90 ms |         - |                    - |                - |         - |         - |      9,360 B |
| Bench_QueuePerformance |   ConcurrentQueueTry |        1000000 |          4 | 330.1 ms |  6.82 ms | 20.01 ms |         - |                    - |          11.5000 |         - |         - |  1,116,912 B |
 */
```

Here are the benchmark results for LockFreeRingBufferQueue  versus ThreadSafeQueue (ReaderWriterLockSlim) versus the standard ConcurrentQueue

```
OS=Windows 10.0.19044.1645 (21H2)
AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3970X, 1 CPU, 64 logical and 32 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.202
  [Host]   : .NET 6.0.4 (6.0.422.16404), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  .NET 6.0 : .NET 6.0.4 (6.0.422.16404), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET 6.0  Runtime=.NET 6.0

| Method                 | m_TestMode           | numRepititions | numThreads | Mean      | Error      | StdDev     | Lock Contentions  |     Gen 0  |     Gen 1  |    Gen 2  | Allocated  |
|----------------------- |--------------------- |--------------- |----------- |----------:| ----------:| ----------:| -----------------:| ----------:| ----------:| ---------:| ----------:|
| Bench_QueuePerformance | RingBufferQueue      | 1000000        | 1          | 80.31 ms  | 3.194 ms   | 8.742 ms   | -                 | 3400.0000  | 1400.0000  | -         | 28,566 KB  |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ThreadSafeQueue      | 1000000        | 1          | 96.60 ms  | 1.910 ms   | 3.901 ms   | -                 | -          | -          | -         | 1 KB       |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ConcurrentQueueCount | 1000000        | 1          | 70.94 ms  | 1.410 ms   | 2.750 ms   | -                 | 500.0000   | 500.0000   | 500.0000  | 2,948 KB   |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ConcurrentQueueTry   | 1000000        | 1          | 49.13 ms  | 2.274 ms   | 6.704 ms   | 0.1250            | -          | -          | -         | 283 KB     |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | RingBufferQueue      | 1000000        | 4          | 367.08 ms | 10.954 ms  | 32.128 ms  | -                 | 3000.0000  | 1000.0000  | -         | 28,566 KB  |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ThreadSafeQueue      | 1000000        | 4          | 253.59 ms | 12.344 ms  | 36.398 ms  | -                 | -          | -          | -         | 1 KB       |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ConcurrentQueueCount | 1000000        | 4          | 341.09 ms | 12.249 ms  | 36.116 ms  | 18.5000           | -          | -          | -         | 1,540 KB   |
| Bench_QueuePerformance | ConcurrentQueueTry   | 1000000        | 4          | 266.15 ms | 13.365 ms  | 39.408 ms  | 11.6667           | 333.3333   | 333.3333   | 333.3333  | 2,223 KB   |
```

Code implementation for each of the benchmarks:

4 threads are queueing items:

```
switch (m_TestMode)
{
    case TestMode.LockFreeQueue:
        for (int I = 0; I < numReps; I++)
        {
            m_queueLockFree.Enqueue(I);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.ThreadSafeQueue:
        for (int I = 0; I < numReps; I++)
        {
            m_queueThreadSafe.Enqueue(I);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.RingBufferQueue:
        for (int I = 0; I < numReps; I++)
        {
            m_queueThreadSafeRingBuffer.Enqueue(I);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.ConcurrentQueueCount:
        for (int I = 0; I < numReps; I++)
        {
            m_queueConcurrent.Enqueue(I);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.ConcurrentQueueTry:
        for (int I = 0; I < numReps; I++)
        {
            m_queueConcurrent.Enqueue(I);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
}
```

Simultaneously 4 threads are dequeuing items

```
switch (m_TestMode)
{
    case TestMode.LockFreeQueue:
        while (ThreadsIsRunning)
        {
            success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                if (m_queueLockFree.Count > 0)
                {
                    m_queueLockFree.DeQueue();
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!ThreadsIsRunning) { break; }
                }
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.ThreadSafeQueue:
        while (ThreadsIsRunning)
        {
            success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                if (m_queueThreadSafe.Count > 0)
                {
                    m_queueThreadSafe.DeQueue();
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!ThreadsIsRunning) { break; }
                }
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.RingBufferQueue:
        while (ThreadsIsRunning)
        {
            success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                m_queueThreadSafeRingBuffer.DeQueue(out success);
                if (!ThreadsIsRunning) { break; }
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.ConcurrentQueueCount:
        while (ThreadsIsRunning)
        {
            success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                // In order to keep this fair we are also checking .Count property
                if (m_queueConcurrent.Count > 0 && m_queueConcurrent.TryDequeue(out item))
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!ThreadsIsRunning) { break; }
                }
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
    case TestMode.ConcurrentQueueTry:
        while (ThreadsIsRunning)
        {
            success = false;
            while (!success)
            {
                if (m_queueConcurrent.TryDequeue(out item))
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!ThreadsIsRunning) { break; }
                }
            }
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref QueueSize);
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: How does your solution compare to a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` under heavy contention? IIRC, that's one of the cases that `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is designed for (and why it's slower in the uncontended case)

Comment: Updated the question and added the benchmarks as well as the code used for benchmarking. My implementation is just marginally faster. But not by any significant amount with one major difference. checking count has no impact on performance.

Comment: Is it necessary that the packages are worked on exact input sequence?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon No it isn't necessary that the working sequence or output sequence matches the input sequence within reason that is. So for example if message 5 in the input shows up as sequence 245 in the output that is still fine. First off I'm using batch sizes of 512 in TorchSharp / Tensorflow.net. To be specific each message has an epoch sequence number and a step sequence number. Since each message has carries its own unique identifiers and sequence identifiers each side can easily buffer and reassemble / sort the messages in any required sequence.

Comment: @tcwicks you could consider posting any additional observations as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), to keep the question clean, and also to get credit for your efforts!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Understood will do. Thanks for pointing this out :) Will put any further additions as a self answer

Comment: I would go for the `LockFreeQueue`, but change it to use `struct` wherever possible. E.g. `SingleLinkNode<T>` could perhaps benefit from this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt to reproduce your observations. I create 8 worker threads, where each thread first enqueues and then dequeues 1,000 items from the queue, in a loop, for a specific duration (1,500 msec). At the end I measure the total number of all enqueue/dequeue operations (by all workers), and I adjust it per second. I also display the memory allocations per second, as well as the [`LockContentionCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.lockcontentioncount) per second.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, "Debug built");
        const int workersCount = 8;
        const int durationOfEachTest = 1500;
        const int batchOperations = 1000;
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workersCount, workersCount);
        Console.WriteLine($"Workers: {workersCount}, " +
            $"ProcessorCount: {Environment.ProcessorCount}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Duration of each test: {durationOfEachTest} msec, " +
            $"Batch enqueue/dequeue: {batchOperations:#,0}");

        // Warmup
        Test(null, new ConcurrentQueue<int>(), 100);
        //Test(null, new ConcurrentStack<int>(), 100);
        //Test(null, new ConcurrentBag<int>(), 100);
        Test(null, new MyConcurrentQueue<int>(), 100);

        Test("ConcurrentQueue", new ConcurrentQueue<int>(), durationOfEachTest);
        //Test("ConcurrentStack", new ConcurrentStack<int>(), durationOfEachTest);
        //Test("ConcurrentBag", new ConcurrentBag<int>(), durationOfEachTest);
        Test("Queue+Lock", new MyConcurrentQueue<int>(), durationOfEachTest);

        static void Test(string title, IProducerConsumerCollection<int> queue,
            int durationMsec)
        {
            if (title != null) Console.WriteLine();
            if (title != null) Console.WriteLine($"{title}");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            var lcc0 = Monitor.LockContentionCount;
            var mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var workers = Enumerable.Range(1, workersCount).Select(n => Task.Run(() =>
            {
                long outerLoops = 0;
                while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < durationMsec)
                {
                    outerLoops++;
                    for (int i = 0; i < batchOperations; i++) queue.TryAdd(i);
                    for (int i = 0; i < batchOperations; i++) queue.TryTake(out _);
                }
                return outerLoops * batchOperations * 2;
            })).ToArray();
            long totalLoops = Task.WhenAll(workers).Result.Sum();
            var mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
            var lcc1 = Monitor.LockContentionCount;
            if (title != null) Console.WriteLine(
                $"Total operations per second: {(totalLoops * 1000L) / durationMsec:#,0}");
            if (title != null) Console.WriteLine(
                $"Allocated: {(mem1 - mem0) * 1000L / durationMsec:#,0} bytes per second, " +
                $"Lock contention per second: {(lcc1 - lcc0) * 1000L / durationMsec:#,0}");
            if (queue.Count > 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    private class MyConcurrentQueue<T> : IProducerConsumerCollection<T>
    {
        private readonly Queue<T> _queue = new();
        public bool TryAdd(T item)
        {
            lock (_queue) _queue.Enqueue(item); return true;
        }
        public bool TryTake(out T item)
        {
            lock (_queue)
            {
                if (_queue.Count == 0) { item = default; return false; }
                item = _queue.Dequeue(); return true;
            }
        }
        public int Count { get { lock (_queue) return _queue.Count; } }
        public bool IsSynchronized => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public object SyncRoot => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public T[] ToArray() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Output on my PC:

```
Workers: 8, ProcessorCount: 4
Duration of each test: 1500 msec, Batch enqueue/dequeue: 1,000

ConcurrentQueue
Total operations per second: 15,700,000
Allocated: 2,799,621 bytes per second, Lock contention per second: 21

Queue+Lock
Total operations per second: 11,642,666
Allocated: 46,256 bytes per second, Lock contention per second: 10,310
```

Output [on dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kE7KuI):

```
Workers: 8, ProcessorCount: 4
Duration of each test: 1500 msec, Batch enqueue/dequeue: 1,000

ConcurrentQueue
Total operations per second: 14,281,333
Allocated: 5,596,789 bytes per second, Lock contention per second: 24

Queue+Lock
Total operations per second: 22,566,666
Allocated: 46,768 bytes per second, Lock contention per second: 4,912
```

So on my PC the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is a bit faster, while on dotnetfiddle.net is a bit slower than a `Queue`+`lock`. I have no idea why. The lock contention is also higher on my PC, which affects primarily the `Queue`+`lock` implementation (it makes it slower). Changing the number of workers or the number of batch operations affects these measurements in various ways.

The `ConcurrentQueue<T>` allocates less than a byte per operation, which is not that much in the grand scheme of things. But of course the `Queue`+`lock` is the clear winner in this aspect, since it's essentially allocation-free.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also observed similar behavior when the thread count is equal to or above physical processor count. So on my machine if I run it with over 32 concurrent threads then ConcurrentQueue<T> wins. Otherwise lock plus queue wins. However instead of using Lock (Monitor) if you switch to ReaderWriterLockSlim with write locks then queue + Lock performance improves a bit. Regardless however my core issue though is how to come up with a higher performance queue that does not slow down so drastically when there is thread contention. My Lock Free Queue attempt failed :(

Comment: @tcwicks: What actual hardware are you testing on?  Differences in inter-core latency and memory-level parallelism might have some kind of effect. (A big Xeon has higher memory latency than a desktop CPU with a few cores, since the interconnect is more complex among other things).  A Zen CPU with low inter-core latency within a CCX, but higher to cores in another CCX, could also make a difference. Same goes for the testing in this answer, at least for your own PC where you know what HW you have. You *could* include code to get the CPUID string on the online IDE you used, to check AMD vs. Intel

Comment: @Peter Cordes  I'm running this on an AMD Threadripper 32 core 64 thread box with a gigabyte trx40 designare motherboard. Ram is G.SKILL Trident Z 3200 Ram Timing 16-18-18-38. Until the thread count gets close to 32 ReaderWriterLockSlim beats everything else. Having said that I've also benchmarked it on a 24 core Intel HP Omen laptop. pretty much the same story. I'm beginning to think that without a lock free queue structure this is probably about as fast as its going to go.

Comment: @PeterCordes FYI my PC is an "AMD Athlon(tm) 5350 APU with Radeon(tm) R3, 2050 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)". The dotnetfiddle.net server [runs on Linux-Ubuntu](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BvzAWg). I don't know if it's possible to read the processor information on this system, with C#.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/T2gATi is a copypasta C# program to read Linux's `/proc/cpuinfo` and print it on the console. On that run, it happened to be running on a "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8168 CPU @ 2.70GHz", a relatively old Skylake-server.  (In a VM instance where CPUID says it's 4 logical cores sharing 2 physical cores: only 2 different "core id" values. That hopefully reflects reality that the VM's cores are running on both hyperthreads on two physical cores of the 24-core CPU, hopefully on the same package not separate sockets.)  33M L3 cache, but highish inter-core latency.

Comment: Totally right. Intercore latency / CPU interconnect latency etc... plays a huge part at this level of performance. I keep explaining to devops docker people that SQL Server when targeting maximum performance needs to run on bare metal but most just don't get it. In these scenarios AMD (or Intel) CPU core interconnect in a single socket high core count CPU will always outperform a dual socket or quad socket solution. Which will always outperform a VM solution, etc... Interconnect on a VM running on an old Skylake is no match against bare metal single socket threadripper 32 Core or I9 12 Core.

Comment: @tcwicks: Virtualization adds some overhead, especially to page-table operations (like mmap / munmap) and to page walks on TLB miss, but a pure microbenchmark of inter-core latency (like bouncing a cache line between two cores, or having multiple contend for it) shouldn't have any VM exits or page walks.  I'd expect the measured latency for two threads running on physical cores to be the same whether it's bare metal or under a hypervisor, like 40ns to 80ns.

Comment: @tcwicks: Once virtual->physical address translation is done (in a load or store execution unit by consulting the TLB, which caches the nested page tables), it's out of the way; cache coherency and the actual interconnect between cores work on physical addresses.  Virtual addresses are just within a single core.  I'm not disputing your performance observations for that application, just saying that virtualization itself shouldn't increase inter-core latency *unless the hypervisor schedules your VMs guest CPU cores on more distant phys cores than you got on bare metal*.

Comment: @tcwicks: So virtualization overhead might be more about VM exits and more expensive page walks, and stuff like that, moreso than actual inter-core latency increases.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your right. Micro benchmarks will be less affected by say a VM exit. However what I'm talking about here is sustained continuous load. Even in the case of micro benchmarks like BenchmarkDotNet,it runs multiple iterations with forced GC collect etc... in between. In the above benchmarks it ran upwards of 40 iterations in order to get a stable average. This leaves room for VM exits. Also in the solution that I am trying to build it will run continuously for weeks on end with all cores at 100% struggling to keep up with the GPU's.

Comment: @tcwicks: Sure, I'm not disputing that VMs have overhead.  All I'm nitpicking is that it's separate from inter-core latency, which just depends on the hardware and the interconnect / cache coherency protocol between the pair of physical cores two threads are actually executing on (and maybe contention on the interconnect from other cores), but not virtualization.  (If you're talking about some higher-level round-trip between threads that might be delayed by VM exits, I wouldn't call that just "inter-core latency" anymore.)

Comment: @PeterCordes The high level process flow kind of like, data preparation, feeding and compiling results runs on the CPU cores. This includes for example Numpy style resizing, slicing and reshaping of float arrays. Calculating aggregate stats. Serialization of data messages, Tensorflow.Net / TorchSharp framework overheads like preparing GPU kernels etc... Thing is a single 3090 GPU is extremely fast, The smaller the batch size the higher the CPU overheads  Keeping it fully loaded on smaller batch sizes is very straightforward using 4GHz AMD / Intel CPU cores.

Comment: @PeterCordes However when we the problem arises when we try to run the model across multiple 3090 GPU's. A single threaded CPU side can barely keep one GPU at 100%. Which means to keep four of these cards running a multi threaded solution is needed. The moment I go there I run into issues around the cost of thread syncronization mechanisms when there is contention. Plus a single dataset generator (Unity simulation) cannot generate enough source data so we need multiple which means a super fast message queue to coordinate all of the parallel dataset generators (unity simulation instances)

Comment: @PeterCordes Also again you are right. The higher level round trip between threads is technically not inter-core latency. Here I'm actually running on bare metal. Tight loops where threads on different cores are competing for shared resources. Now the bottleneck is thread synchronization overheads. Memory barriers, semaphores, monitor etc... Interlocked compare and swap technique doesn't work since the data structures are too big so CPU overhead plus GC overhead makes it not worth it. I have no idea how to make this go any faster without some lock free queue that does not create GC overheads.

Comment: @tcwicks: an array-based ring buffer lock-free queue doesn't need to alloc/free anything.  Ideally it can just hand references to objects between threads, or copy an object.  Of course, an MPMC queue using array slots instead of a linked list can mean contention between threads to read/write a `readpos` and `writepos`.  [Lock-free Progress Guarantees](//stackoverflow.com/q/45907210) is an interesting look at one in C++.  It may cost more in extra contention than GC costs you with a simpler linked-list queue (which is only simple with GC to  solve the deallocation problem).

Comment: @PeterCordes Benchmarked Linked list queue is slower due to GC. But why is the ring buffer queue method still slower than ReaderWriterLockSlim based queue. It uses a lock only when adding or dequeuing a new buffer to its internal queue. All updates to head and tail pointers are atomic using interlocked. Removed Volatile on head and tail as not needed. Still it is slightly slower. Somehow Its spinning more than the spinlock inside ReaderWriterLockSlim in the lock based queue. Thx for the link "a POP thread that observes an in-progress PUSH would need to complete the PUSH". Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want more throughput then stop causing unnecessary thread contention. Pair up your Consumers and Producers. Give each Consumer it's own Queue and have a designated Producer add messages to it.

If your Production vs Consumption ratio is close to 1:1 then don't even bother with a Queue. Have a couple slots in memory for each Producer to store messages and have the paired Consumer poll those slots.

Here's an example of the memory slots idea vs ConcurrentQueue. The FastSwap class requires a 1 Producer to 1 Consumer pairing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TestQueue
{
    class Program
    {
        const int tries = 10;
        const int tasks = 4; // producers and consumers
        const int iterations = 500000;
        static Dummy[] dummies = Enumerable.Range(0, iterations).Select(i => new Dummy() { X = i }).ToArray();
        static Stopwatch s1;
        static Stopwatch s2;
        static Task[] t1 = new Task[tasks * 2];
        static Task[] t2 = new Task[tasks * 2];
        static long a1;
        static long a2;
        static volatile int c1 = 0;
        static volatile int c2 = 0;
        static ConcurrentQueue<Dummy> q1;
        static FastSwap<Dummy> q2;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // 1
            a1 = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t < tries; t++)
            {
                q1 = new ConcurrentQueue<Dummy>();
                c1 = 0;
                s1 = new Stopwatch();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                s1.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks * 2; i++)
                {
                    if ((i & 1) == 0)
                    { // producer
                        t1[i] = new Task(() =>
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++)
                            {
                                q1.Enqueue(dummies[x]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    { // consumer
                        t1[i] = new Task(() => {
                            Dummy tmp;
                            while (c1 < (iterations * tasks))
                            {
                                if (q1.TryDequeue(out tmp))
                                {
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref c1);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    t1[i].Start();
                }
                Task.WaitAll(t1);
                s1.Stop();
                a1 += s1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Test {t} Queue 1 result: {s1.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Queue 1 avg: {a1 / tries} ms");
            // 2
            a2 = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t < tries; t++)
            {
                q2 = new FastSwap<Dummy>(tasks);
                c2 = 0;
                s2 = new Stopwatch();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                s2.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < tasks * 2; i++)
                {
                    if ((i & 1) == 0)
                    { // producer
                        int proIdx = i >> 1;
                        t2[i] = new Task(() =>
                        {
                            for (int x = 0; x < iterations; x++)
                            {
                                q2.Insert(proIdx, dummies[x]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    { // consumer
                        int conIdx = (i - 1) >> 1;
                        t2[i] = new Task(() => {
                            Dummy tmp;
                            while (c2 < (iterations * tasks))
                            {
                                if ((tmp = q2.Take(conIdx)) != null)
                                {
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref c2);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    t2[i].Start();
                }
                Task.WaitAll(t2);
                s2.Stop();
                a2 += s2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Test {t} Queue 2 result: {s2.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Queue 2 avg: {a2 / tries} ms");
            //
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public class Dummy
        {
            public int X;
            public Dummy() { }
        }
        public class FastSwap<T> where T : class, new()
        {
            const int slots = 2; // slots per producer
            readonly int _producers;
            readonly T[] _buffer;
            public FastSwap(int producers)
            {
                _producers = producers;
                _buffer = new T[_producers * slots];
            }
            public void Insert(int producerIndex, T item)
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    // wait for a free slot
                    // unroll based on # of slots
                    if(_buffer[producerIndex] == null)
                    {
                        _buffer[producerIndex] = item;
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (_buffer[producerIndex + _producers] == null)
                    {
                        _buffer[producerIndex + _producers] = item;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            public T Take(int producerOndex)
            {
                T tmp = null;
                //int r = 100;
                //while (--r != 0) 
                //{
                    // check the slots for data
                    // unroll based on # of slots
                    if (_buffer[producerOndex] != null)
                    {
                        tmp = _buffer[producerOndex];
                        _buffer[producerOndex] = null;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if (_buffer[producerOndex + _producers] != null)
                    {
                        tmp = _buffer[producerOndex + _producers];
                        _buffer[producerOndex + _producers] = null;
                        //break;
                    }
                //}
                return tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The more speed you require the more single-use (less generic) your solution will end up being.